# CSS not being applied in CGI script

Tags: python, css, cgi

I wrote this cgi script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi


print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print"<html>"
print"<title>Wedmed Search engine</title>"
print"""<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css"/>
<body>

<div class="img" position="center">
    <h1>
        WebMED</h1>
    </div>

<form action="/cgi-bin/hello.py" method="POST">

    <input type="text" size="50" name="data" value=""><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
</body></html>"""
```

The problem is css is not working with my cgi script. It works perfectly fine with html code.
can anyone please help??

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a problem with relative/absolute addressing.
Try to set the absolute address to your css file.

If the file structure on your server is

```
/css
    /stylesheet1.css
```

then href would be "/css/stylesheet1.css"

or if stylesheet1.css is directly in htdocs
then href would be "/stylesheet1.css"

Answer (score 0):

If the python script and the css file are in the same directory, try this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet.css" />
```

It is important to add the '/' before mentioning the css file's location.

Answer (score 0):

in the similar situation i changed code in the following way:

from

```
...
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print"<html>"
...
```

to

```
...
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print ""
print"<html>"
...
```

also in my case i used another form of print

```
...
print("Content-type: text/html")
print("")
print("<html>")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that isn't the best but does the trick for me.

Put your whole style-sheet in `stylesheet1.css` as you already did and then write this in your python file

```
f = open('stylesheet1.css', 'r')
style = ''
for i in f:
    style += i
head = '''
    <head>
    <style>
    %s
    <style>
    </head>''' % (style)
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print"<html>"
print head
print """<body>

<div class="img" position="center">
    <h1>
        WebMED</h1>
    </div>

<form action="/cgi-bin/hello.py" method="POST">

    <input type="text" size="50" name="data" value=""><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
</body></html>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a path and privs issue. 
Put your *.css in the html directory (/var/www/html) instead of ./cgi-bin.
The url in this case should look like:
href="/stylesheet.css"

Answer (score 0):

First, in your code, if you want to use css in python cgi, you may add head.

Second, you may need to make sure the configuration is fine, which I mean the server you use.

Below is an example for a simple hello.py, i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

html ="""Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>"""
print html
```

In the example, apache is used, and the structure is,

```
# ls /var/www/cgi-bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 263 Nov  4 05:55 hello.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  83 Nov  4 06:38 styles.css
```

Thus, css needs to be enabled in `httpd.conf`

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AddHandler default-handler .css
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Finally, you should be able to see,

[image]

That is because of css, i.e.

```
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
p {
  color: red;
}
```